# Fast double file read in C

Tags: c, file, io

I have a large file containing floating point numbers and I want to read them.

```
   52.881 49.779 21.641 37.230 23.417 7.506 120.190 1.240 79.167 82.397 126.502 47.377 112.583 124.590 103.339 5.821 24.566 38.916 42.576
```

This is just the beggining of the file. It has 10000000 numbers.

I got this code but I don't know how to print the numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sysexits.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int fd; 
    size_t bytes_read, bytes_expected = 1000000*sizeof(double); 
    double *data;
    char *infile = "file.dat";

    if ((fd = open(infile,O_RDONLY)) < 0) 
        err(EX_NOINPUT, "%s", infile);

    if ((data = malloc(bytes_expected)) == NULL)
        err(EX_OSERR, "data malloc");

    bytes_read = read(fd, data, bytes_expected);

   if (bytes_read != bytes_expected) 
       err(EX_DATAERR, "Read only %d of %d bytes", 
         bytes_read, bytes_expected);

   /* print all */

   free(data);

   exit(EX_OK);
}
```

Comment: I didn't need to read your code to se a problem `100000000*sizeof(double)`, why that value? Why SOOOOO HUGE? Also, `bytes_read` is not necessarily equal to `bytes_expected` for many reasons, and please post some of the file's content.

Comment: Just an example. I can make it lower.

Comment: When you open the file, do you see garbage characters or formatted decimal numbers?

Comment: If you had an array of `double`, would you know how to print it? Arrays and pointers are very similar, and you can use similar syntax to access their elements.

Comment: @zaig NEVER USE MAGIC CONSTANTS. Unless they are truly magic like in the header of a file format.

Comment: @anonymoose I see formated decimal numbers.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: I tried printing data[0] but it was 0.000000.

Comment: @zaig Binary Data != Text Data (*except sometimes, text itself*), your file is text data and you are reading it as binary.

Comment: *"I see formated decimal numbers*", then better show some example lines.

Comment: If the data in the file is *text* you should read it as text not as binary data. Use the standard C functions instead (like `fopen`, `fscanf`, etc.)

Comment: When you ask for help with reading a file, show the file.

Comment: @nicomp I edited and put some of the first numbers of the file.

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to read a text file as if the data was binary, so you will read some bytes but the `double` values stored in the array will not be the values that you wanted to read from the file, you can probably do this

```
FILE *file;
double *array;
size_t count;
const char *infile = "file.dat";

file = fopen(infile, "r");
if (file == NULL)
    return -1;
count = 0;
while (fscanf(file, "%*lf") == 1)
    count += 1;
rewind(file);
array = malloc(count * sizeof(*array));
if (array == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "cannot allocate %zu bytes!\n", count * sizeof(*array));
    fclose(file);
    return -1;
}
// Read the values into the array
for (size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    fscanf(file, "%lf", &array[i]);
}
// Print the array
for (size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    fprintf(stdout, "%f\n", array[i]);
}
// Release memory
free(array);
```

Comment: that was my first approach but I wanted to try something that may be faster

Comment: As the question's title carries the word "*fast*" I tend to argue that for counting the numbers (pass 1) it might be faster to count the spaces, but to do a full double-scanning.

Comment: @zaig: If you have text  (that is `char`s) and want `double`s, the work of conversion needs to be done. It's not for free. It won't happen magically in 0s.

Comment: @zaig: Slow code that works is better than fast code that doesn't.

Comment: @zaig Also, you will not be reading this often or will you? Because the optimization might be to cache the values and avoid reading them a lot.

Comment: Then why you worry about performance? If the whole file content fits in the system memroy then you will not gain that much by optimizing this more than it is. But if the contents don't fit in memory or system memory is huge, then more needs to be known about the use case and why is performace so importan.

Answer (score -1):

Since you want a fast solution, maybe you have to sacrifice memory.
The faster manner of reading a file is in binary form.
Thus, I would obtain the file size with an efficient method,
then I would allocate memory accordingly,
with the idea of uploading the entire file to memory.
There, since memory reading is faster than file reading,
the data can be quickly read by using `sscanf(...)`.
We can also observe that each floating point number
needs **at least 3 characters** to be stored in a text file:

- 1 char for the dot (`'.'`),
- 1 char for some digit,
- and 1 char for
  a space (' ') used to separating a value from its succesor in the
  file.

Thus, the file size divided by 3 will be the upper bound for the size of the array of doubles.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
  char *filename = "file.dat";
  FILE *F = fopen(filename, "rb");
  fseek(F, 0L, SEEK_END);
  long int filesize = ftell(F);
  rewind(F);
  char *data = malloc(filesize+1);
  fread(data, filesize, 1, F);
  data[filesize] = '\0';                              // End of string, just in case
  fclose(F);

  // The desired data will be stored in array:  
  double *array = malloc(sizeof(double) * filesize/3);

  int ret;
  int n;       // represents the no chars in a sscanf(...) reading
  double *a = array;
  while (1) {      // Infinite loop...
    ret = sscanf(data, " %lg%n", a, &n);
    if (ret == EOF) break;   // <<---- EXIT POINT of the loop
    a++;
    data += n;
  }

  long int array_size = a - array + 1;
}
```